# How can i replace the given indices of a string using regex

Tags: regex

I want to replace certain indices of a string such as:

"123456789" i want 2nd and 8th indices to replace each other.

So the result will be "129456783". How can i achieve that ?

EDIT :

Thanks to answer , i found my solution and i am writing it here just in case anyone needs it.

```
var str = "123456789";
var res = str.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{5})(\d{1})/g, "$1$4$3$2");
```

This should do the trick !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using capturing groups and backreferences.

Regex:

```
(..)(.)(.....)(.)
```

Replacement pattern:

```
$1$4$3$2
```

Note that the exact syntax depends on regex flavor (i.e. the tool used). 
Some tools define backreferences via backslash, i.e. `\1\4\3\2`, and some tools don't support backreferences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found my solution thanks to you.